# Crashlytics highlighting line without code

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

About 1% of my users are crashing in my app and I can't figure out why, or replicate the issue. Crashlytics just says

> Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000102bf023c
>   specialized SearchTableViewController.tableView(UITableView,
>   didSelectRowAt : IndexPath) -> ()

and it highlights a line that doesn't even really have code in it: line 196 which just has the closing "}" of the didSelectRowAt indexPath function. I've been playing around with it for a few weeks.

Patterns:

- All are iOS 11
- Almost all seem to have less than 150 MB of RAM free at time of crash

Stack trace here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdYf5.jpg

Code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  if chosenFoodObject == nil{
    // User Chose a Food
    chosenFoodObject = latestHitArray[indexPath.row]

    // Update food download index
    updateDownloadScore(foodID: chosenFoodObject!["objectID"] as! String)

    // Gives size options for selected food
    var sizeArray: [String]
    sizeArray = Array(chosenFoodObject!.keys)
    listResults.removeAll()

    if let highlightIndex = sizeArray.index(of: "_highlightResult") {
      sizeArray.remove(at: highlightIndex)
    }

    if let nameIndex = sizeArray.index(of: "name") {
      sizeArray.remove(at: nameIndex)
    }

    if let downloadIndex = sizeArray.index(of: "downloads") {
      sizeArray.remove(at: downloadIndex)
    }

    if let photoIndex = sizeArray.index(of: "photoURL") {
      sizeArray.remove(at: photoIndex)
    }

    if let idIndex = sizeArray.index(of: "objectID") {
      sizeArray.remove(at: idIndex)
    }

    for word in sizeArray{
      listResults.append(word)
    }

    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
  else{
    // User chose a size
    chosenSize = listResults[indexPath.row]

    showFoodAlertController()
  }
}   //CRASH HAPPENS HERE
```

Comment: I guest the line `tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)` cause crash. Has too much question about it. But you should avoid force unwrap and get the element direct by index (`array[index]`), it can be crash

Comment: If you will remove `!` with `value ?? defaultValue` crash will be remove.

Comment: @QuocNguyen thanks for the answer - what exactly is wrong with tebleView.setContentOffset? Is there a better way to scroll back to the top of the table view?

Comment: @Jake when you don't call `setContentOffset` in main thread, it cause the crash app. I can only guest it. You must reproduce the crash first. It will be more helpful